# Which DSP filter-algorithms are simple to implement?

Tags: c, algorithm, filter, filtering, signal-processing

I have a datalogger with very little memory, and I want to implement support for filters in the firmware.

Which types of filters can I implement easily without the need for buffers or huge functions?

One that comes to mind is an exponential moving average, something like:

```
sample = (alpha * new_sample) + (1.0 - alpha) * sample
```

Are there any other well-known DSP-filters that could be accomplished in a few lines?

Comment: Hi! Also your accumulator needs additional memory (for storing the 'accumulator' value. Also, it's no real filter as a filter is supposed to reject 'new_value' when certain criterias are met

Comment: @FloF: depends on your definition. From a signal-processing point-of-view, this is very definitely a filter.

Comment: @FloF Ofcourse it would need memory to hold a couple of variabeles, but it won't need large buffers like FFT and most other DSP-filters need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to implement frequency selective filtering without some buffering. Even the example you give requires a buffer of one sample. First off, [forget about FFT filtering for most realtime data.](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/why-eq-is-done-in-time-domain.html) For most filtering applications, and certainly applications where you are concerned about memory, you will want to use a time-domain filter.

Time-domain filters generally come in two favors, IIR and FIR. Filters are also distinguished based on their "order". The example you gave above is a first order IIR filter. The relevant facts are:

- Broadly speaking, IIR filters require a lower order than FIR for a given response.
- A filter can be implemented with a number of memory locations equal to the order of the filter. This is not always the best way to implement a filter, but it can be done using something called [Direct Form II](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp3/Direct_Form_II.html).

For a broad range of applications, second order IIR filters (sometimes called "biquads") are an excellent choice. I have a tutorial on second order biquads [here](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html). It is oriented towards audio applications, but you will probably find it useful. Keep in mind this tutorial uses Direct Form I which is more numerically stable, but requires more memory locations. At four locations, though, I don't think it's much to fret about even for a highly memory starved application.